# PHP array not working as expected

Tags: php

I am making a list in `messages.php` which displays all the active conversations the logged in user (`$username`) has.

What is classed as an "active conversation"? (What should be listed in the li..)

- Assume I am logged in as Alice. Alice sends a message to Fred, this is an active conversation where the `$username` (Alice) is sending a message to `$user` (Fred).
- Assume I am logged in as Alice. Fred sends a message to Alice. This is also an active conversation.
- Summary: Any messages to `$username` (logged in user) and any messages from `$username`should be listed, only ONCE.

**Current behavior:**

Currently, with the code displayed below, an `li` is being generated for every message I send (every row in the `private_messages` table relating to the `$username`).

For example:

- Again, assume I am logged in as Alice.
- Alice sends a message to Fred saying - "Hello Fred".
- One list element is generated stating Fred's firstname.
- If, as Alice, I send another message to Fred, it will still display one `li` element for `Fred` - Which is good, this is what I want, as the logged in user, I want to see the user I am taking with.
- However, if I log off, sign in a `Fred`, and reply back to Alice, it will generate another `li` element, but this time with the logged in users credentials, so an `li` would be generated stating Fred's first name etc.
- What I need is all this to be in one `li` since the conversation is between two people.

**This is my current code**:

```
<?php
$displayed = [];
// get number of messages from a specific user to the logged in user
$get_mess = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE message_to = '$username' AND message_from ='$user'");
$num_msgs = mysqli_num_rows($get_mess);

// getting all the conversations which concern the user logged on.
$con = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE message_from='$username' OR message_to='$username'");
while ($get_con = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con)){
    $msg_from = $get_con['message_from'];
    $msg_to = $get_con['message_to'];

    // get other persons firstname    
    $u_name = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$msg_to'");
    $get_cu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($u_name);
    $got_ufn = $get_cu['first_name'];
    $got_uln = $get_cu['last_name'];    

    if ($msg_to == $username || $msg_from == $username){
        if(!in_array($msg_to, $displayed)) {
            echo "<li class='list' role='presentation'>
                      <div class='parent'>
                          <div class='disp_pic'>
                              <img class='img-rounded' src='$profile_pic2'/>
                          </div>
                          <div class='user_d'>
                              <a href='messages.php?u=$msg_from'> $got_ufn  $got_uln</a>
                          </div>";
            if ($num_msgs == 0){
                // dont display badge
            }else {
                echo "<span id='num_of_msgs_from' class='badge'>"; 
                if ($user == $user){
                    $num_msgs == 0;
                    echo "$num_msgs </span>";
                }else {
                    echo " $num_msgs </span>";
                }
            }
            echo"
                 </div>
             </li>";
             $displayed[] = $msg_to;
        }
    }
} // while closed
?>
```

Comment: Explain what doesn't work and try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: It could be that the other (not logged in) username is in `$msg_from` or `$msg_to`. But most of your code assumes it is in `$msg_to`. For example, `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$msg_to'`. My suggestion would be to make a variable called something like `$other_user` and have logic at the top of your script to determine whether that should be set to `$msg_from` or `$msg_to`.

Comment: Also, this line `if ($msg_to == $username || $msg_from == $username)` does nothing because you're iterating a result set where that is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get other user with something like this:

```
$other_user = ($msg_to == $username) ? $msg_from : $msg_to;
```

And full code will be like this:

```
<?php
$displayed = [];
// get number of messages from a specific user to the logged in user
$get_mess = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM private_messages ".
    "WHERE message_to = '$username' AND message_from ='$user'");
$num_msgs = mysqli_num_rows($get_mess);

// getting all the conversations which concern the user logged on.
$con = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM private_messages ".
    "WHERE message_from='$username' OR message_to='$username'");
while ($get_con = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con)){
    $msg_from = $get_con['message_from'];
    $msg_to = $get_con['message_to'];

    $other_user = ($msg_to == $username) ? $msg_from : $msg_to;

    // get other persons firstname    
    $u_name = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users ".
        "WHERE username ='$other_user'");
    $get_cu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($u_name);
    $got_ufn = $get_cu['first_name'];
    $got_uln = $get_cu['last_name'];

    if ($msg_to == $username || $msg_from == $username){
        if(!in_array($other_user, $displayed)) {
            echo "<li class='list' role='presentation'>
                      <div class='parent'>
                          <div class='disp_pic'>
                              <img class='img-rounded' src='$profile_pic2'/>
                          </div>
                          <div class='user_d'>
                              <a href='messages.php?u=$other_user'> $got_ufn  $got_uln</a>
                          </div>";
            if ($num_msgs == 0){
                // dont display badge
            }else {
                echo "<span id='num_of_msgs_from' class='badge'>";
                if ($user == $user){
                    $num_msgs == 0;
                    echo "$num_msgs </span>";
                }else {
                    echo " $num_msgs </span>";
                }
            }
            echo"
                 </div>
             </li>";
            $displayed[] = $other_user;
        }
    }
} // while closed
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this has resolved some of my issues. Thing is, it is still displaying the same conversation with the `other user` in seperate `li`' elements. For example, Alice sends an message to Fred, one li generated. Fred then replies to Alice, which generates another li, even though it is the same conversation?

Comment: So you need to display each interlocutor only once?

Comment: I change answer with this code: `$displayed[] = $other_user;`

Comment: Yes, this worked, but again, unfortunately, another issue arises. `$displayed[] = $other_user;` works, it makes one li, but say for example, Alice sends two messages to another user known as `Conor`. She messages and receives a message from Conor, this results into two `li` elements being generated. Im guessing `$displayed[] = $other_user;` only works for the person you are currently talking to?

Comment: you are right, I've forgot to fix if condition to this: `if(!in_array($other_user, $displayed)) {`

Comment: Thank you sir! you have helped me quite a lot! much appreciated.